# cross-compilation ros fuerte on nao geode

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, compilation, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone manage to successfully installed ros fuerte, ubuntu 12.04 on nao geode (cross-compilation)?. I have been trying but it seems there is a mismatch with python 2.6 and 2.7 version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63125/cross-compilation-ros-fuerte-on-nao-geode/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried to do so in the past, and it was a true dependency hell... I did manage to compile ROS on the virtual machine they provide, but ROS wouldn't run. You may find more info here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0